# Ways to speed up rendering / plotting performance on plotly.js

Tags: javascript, svg, webgl, plotly

I'm looking for all kinds of ways to speed up the rendering of plots in JavaScript, maybe we can collect some stuff here?

I'm plotting scientific data, around 500 points + errors per trace (between 1 and 4 traces normally). Doesn't sound too much, does it? Now the data changes according to user input - a slider, and my goal is to update the plots as smoothly as possible while dragging the slider. And that's where I realized that im not satisfied with the drawing speed.

Since the y data (+errors) can totally change, I use `Plotly.redraw` - this takes in my case on Chrome about 30-40ms. Seems ok, but considering that I want to present 5-15 plots at the same time, this often adds up to half a second or more. 1 or 2 fps ain't exactly what one would call "smooth". Plus, that's on Chrome, it looks way worse on other Browsers.

So I wonder if redrawing is the only option, and if so, how to speed this up? Any ideas? I tried `type: 'scattergl'`and while this seems to be a big boost (down to 10-15ms), it only works like a charm for small plots with only one trace, I can't manage to get it to work for all 10-15 plots - it throws multiple different errors, not worth mentioning since they are always different on different machines. So my conclusion is, that the `scattergl` interface isn't as mature as svg, but maybe I'm using it wrong?

Sorry for the long text, but now I would be really glad to hear some ideas on how to speed things up.

Comment: Disclaimer: I posted this question also on the Plotly forum, but I thought useful answers are here better accessible for a wider audience, I will combine the collected information. ;)

Comment: I dont know the internals of plotly at all so take this with a grain of salt. It is possible that plotly is not written for quickly drawing dynamic graphs and thus not optimized for it. Now, I dont know how much work plotly does for the other stuff, but if my only requirement is to draw 500 points at different xy coordinates each frame, this can be trivially accomplished by the 2d-canvas api or webgl api at 60fps.

Comment: Well, without a framework it probably would be a lot of work to make a fully functional, interactive graph.

Yes, I do think HTML5 Canvas would be great, but I couldn't find a library with support for errors/individual x values with Canvas. On the other hand, plotly does support webgl, but sadly I can't manage to get it to work without errors (too many webgl objects, not rendering properly etc.etc.) - Canvas would be the way to go. :(

Comment: A recent blog that shows how someone used WebWorkers to make smooth plotly response to slider http://www.danderson00.com/2017/06/parallelizing-javascript-workloads.html

Comment: Have a read through https://www.somesolvedproblems.com/2018/07/how-do-i-make-plotly-faster.html which has some suggestions. I implemented `scattergl` and `Plotly.react` for a "large" scatter plot (±38000 points) and saw a big decrease in draw time